# How to create a firebase project using googleapi in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code

```
const firebasedatabase = google.firebasedatabase({version: 'v1beta', auth});
const projectId = "test";
const databaseId = 'test';

firebasedatabase.projects.locations.instances.create({
   databaseId: databaseId,
  `projects/{project-number\}/locations/{location-id\}`.
   parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/us-central1`,
   validateOnly: true,
   requestBody: {},
});
```

Error
GaxiosError: Project does not exist.

Already I have create a project manullay in google cloud.

I trying to full auto setup firebase using googleapi.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.